# Javascript Hidden/Show data as input Radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a code which displays an information by clicking on a RADIO and other information by clicking on another RADIO.

Works normally, but when I update the page, even CHECKED, shows no information. Then I have to click again on the RADIO that is already CHECKED information to appear.

Anyone know how to solve?

Follow the code below:

```
<script>
// COLOR BG OR IMG BG
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='userBgOrImg']").click(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
    }); 
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
    .desc { display: none; }
</style>


<div><label><input type="radio" name="userBgOrImg" value="1" <?php $id = $res_select["id"]; if ( $userBgOrImg == 1 ) { echo "checked=\"checked\"";} else { echo "";}?>>Cor de Fundo</label></div>  
<div><label><input type="radio" name="userBgOrImg" value="2" <?php $id = $res_select["id"]; if ( $userBgOrImg == 2 ) { echo "checked=\"checked\"";} else { echo "";}?>>Imagem de Fundo</label></div>  
<div> <br /> <br /> </div>
<div id="1" class="desc">
    <label for="userBgBody">Cor do fundo do Site</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control bscp span12" value="<?php $id = $res_select["id"]; echo $userBgBody; ?>" id="userBgBody" name="userBgBody">
    <hr />
</div>

<div id="2" class="desc">
    <label for="userImgBody">Imagem de fundo do site</label>
    <input type="text" class="span12" name="userImgBody" id="userImgBody" placeholder="Imagem do fundo do site" value="<?php $id = $res_select["id"]; echo $userImgBody; ?>" />
    <hr />

    <label for="userImgBodyRepeat">Repetir imagem de fundo</label>
    <span> <input type="radio" name="userImgBodyRepeat" value="repeat"> Sim</span> <span> <input type="radio" name="userImgBodyRepeat" value="no-repeat" selected="selected"> Não
    <hr />
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: works fine in this fiddle check out..http://jsbin.com/OGoVoJI/6/edit

Comment: @Vitor de Sousa, your code is not working because you have assigned a click for a radio button, generally a check event is attached to a radio button.Try to assign a check event for a radio button and test. hope that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var did=$("input[name$='userBgOrImg']:checked").val();
    if(did)
    {
       $("#"+did).show();
    }
    // your remaining code
});// document.ready function close
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KrtB8/)

Comment: Work now! \o/
Thanks!! :)

Comment: I can not confirm how right answer next, but his is working perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to try

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name$='userBgOrImg']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $("div.desc").hide();
        if(this.checked) {
            $("#"+test).show();
        }
    }).filter(':checked').change(); 
});
```

Comment: Rohan Kumar help me too with right answer.. 
thank you too to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Tr this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("input[name$='userBgOrImg']").click(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value)
 {
    $("#"+value).show();
 }
});
```